# Vectorize a For Loop that search for elements in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, search

I have two arrays that look like this:

Array 1 (locs_array) is a 2D array containing pairs of values I call lon and lat e.g.

```
array([[-122.463425,   47.195741],
       [-122.498139,   47.190166]])
```

Array 2 (parents_array) is also a 2D array containing the following columns [id, centerlon, centerlat, upperlon, lowerlon, upperlat, lowerlat] e.g.:

```
array([[   1.        , -122.463425  ,   47.195741  , -122.46331271,
        -122.46353729,   47.19585367,   47.19562833],
       [   2.        , -122.498149  ,   47.190275  , -122.49803671,
        -122.49826129,   47.19038767,   47.19016233]])
```

To put a little context, the first array is a list of lon/lat locations while the second array contains definitions for a grid system which is achieved by storing the center, upper and lower coordinates of the lon and lat.

I'm basically trying to find the fastest way of finding which grids (in array 2) the individual locations belong to (in array 1).

This is what I'm doing so far:

This is my function to find the parent for a given lon/lat pair:

```
def _findFirstParent(self, lon, lat, parents_array):
    parentID = -1
    a = np.where(parents_array[:,3] >= lon)[0] # indices with upperLon >= lon
    b = np.where(parents_array[:,4] <= lon)[0] # indices with lowerLon <= lon
    c = np.intersect1d(a, b) # lon matches

    d = np.where(parents_array[:,5] >= lat)[0] # indices with upperLat >= lat
    e = np.where(parents_array[:,6] <= lat)[0] # indices with lowerLat <= lat
    f = np.intersect1d(d, e) # lat matches

    g = np.intersect1d(c, f) # both match
    if len(g) > 0:
        parentID = g[0]
    return parentID
```

And I call this using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(locs_array)):
     each_lon = locs_array[i][0]
     each_lat = locs_array[i][1]
     parentID = findFirstParent(each_lon, each_lat, parents_array)
```

The Array 1 (Locations array) contains over 100 million records but I figure I can break this down to smaller chunks if needed.
The Array 2 (Grids array) contains over a million records.

What options do I have to make this faster? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what should happen with returned `parentID` ?

Comment: I know that numba is a good tool if you want to compile your function to use vectorization. It also makes it easy to use parallelism with `prange`, e.g. `for i in prange(number_of_chunks)`(one thread handles one chunk of locs_array). Also, maybe you could loop over the grids array once to create a binary search tree.

Comment: I just stack parentID into another array and use it to find the parent details later when needed

Comment: That is not a 7D array. It is a 2D array with seven columns. Is there any structure to the data in that array? e.g. are they sorted by lat/lon?

Comment: Yes we can assume they are sorted.

Comment: Tuples are much faster that lists of the data does not need to be mutated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to vectorize such a loop is broadcasting to force numpy to compare any entry from `loc_array` to any entry from `parent_array`.

For example, if you are trying to find, for each integer of A,  which integer of B is multiple of it, instead of iterating on values of A, you can

```py
A=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
B=np.array([11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])

res = B[None,:]%A[:,None] == 0
```

This returns a 2D array, such as `res[i,j]` is True iff `B[j]` is a multiple of `A[i]`. Then `np.argmax(B[None,:]%A[:,None] == 0, axis=1)` gives the answer (assuming there is always one, which is the case here)

So, in your case

```py
(locs_array[None,:,0]<=parents_array[:,None,3]) & (locs_array[None,:,0]>=parents_array[:,None,4]) & (locs_array[None,:,1]<=parents_array[:,None,5]) & (locs_array[None,:,1]>=parents_array[:,None,6])
```

is a 2D array whose value of index `[i,j]` is True iff `locs_array[j]` is within boundaries of `parents_array[i]`

So

```py
idx = np.argmax((locs_array[None,:,0]<=parents_array[:,None,3]) & (locs_array[None,:,0]>=parents_array[:,None,4]) & (locs_array[None,:,1]<=parents_array[:,None,5]) & (locs_array[None,:,1]>=parents_array[:,None,6]), axis=0)
```

is an array of `len(locs_array)` integers, each integer being the index of an entry of `parents_array` in which each location is.
In other words, `idx[j]=i` means that `locs_array[j]` is within boundaries of `parents_array[i]`. Which, I believe, is what you want.

Two warnings tho

- That's assume that there is always an answer. If a entry `j` of `loc_array` is withing no boundaries from any entry of `parents_array`, then `idx[j]` would be 0. So you may need, either to double check result if it is 0 (because 0 could mean both that the location in included in `parents_array[0]` or that it is included in none). Or, a better solution, would be to have a sentinel: let `parents_array[0]` be an impossible entry (for example upper bound is smaller than lower bound, so nothing can be included in it). Then, you know that if index is 0, it means that there is no solution.
- That is just the vectorization of your algorithm. I am pretty sure it is way faster than your implementation. Because you are iterating in python (with your for loop), while I am iterating in numpy (letting broadcasting do all the combinations). But that is still the exact same computation : compare all `locs_array[j]` with all `parents_array[i]`. It is just that numpy handle the for loop for us. So, again, certainly way faster (can't benchmark it, since you didn't provide a [mre]), but still same algorithm. What was suggested in comments is another (faster, with a different O complexity) algorithm, that can benefit on the knowledge that `parents_array` is sorted. Which allows, for example dichotomy search. But is not that easy to vectorize.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I believe this is what I'm looking for - a way to vectorise this problem. The solution doesn't seem to work though. I get a value of zeros in idx even when I'm sure the entries are present. I used the example in the question as locs_array and parents_array. I should get a value of [0, 1] in my output array, but it's return [0,0]

Comment: There's a slight error in the <= and >=. Fixed that and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for this. I never thought this could be vectorized. I will sure put a dummy entry in row 0 so I can trap that special case. 2 questions: does this return the first or last match? does the parent array need to be sorted for this to work?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I misread the upper and lower bounds (`parents[3]` and `parents[5]` are upper, not lower bounds). For your questions: `argmax` returns the first match. And array doesn't need to be sorted. This usage of broadcasting is just a way to implement a nested loop and try all combinations. I would even say that this is a drawback of the method: if `parent` array were sorted, then this method would still work, of course, but it could not take advantage of `parent` being sorted, and would still explore one by one all combinations (very efficiently sure)